# Overflow pipe has come off the sink

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, overflow

We have a Corian sink and the plastic over flow pipe has popped loose.
It looks like a cable tie was used on it. 
We put it in in 2012
Double sinks. The other sink is fine.
I don’t want to call the plumber as it will be at least $100 to fix it

Any suggestions??

Comment: "over flow pipe has popped loose"; we need a bit more info please. Can you explain how the pipe was originally attached, or describe how it joins with the drain pipe? A picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: It must of been glued in place. I’ll have to call the plumber who installed it??

Answer (score 1):

These are normally glued in position. I have seen silicon sealer work when held in place until fully cured , I have seen epoxy used and any leaks fixes with sealer. The toughest part cleaning any and all residue prior to glueing back in place. The next hardest part is holding in place long enough to fully cure.

Comment: _holding in place_, cue the zip ties...

Comment: I used gorilla duct tape on the last one I did but you could link a few zip ties to make it around and pull tight.